# Using MDX in SSAS tabular get first 10 days of each month

Tags: ssas, dax, ssas-tabular

I am trying to dynamically get the dates, starting from begging of month to current date using SSAS Tabular - DAX, I have tried many date functions but I couldn't end up with solution, so is there any idea to share pls ?

Answer (score 2):

The following DAX function will return a table of DATES for each day from the start of the current month through today:

```
DatesMTD = CALENDAR(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()), 1), TODAY())
```

Answer (score 2):

To be able to filter the dates for the first 10 days, create a calculated column that identifies as a date in this range

```
1st to 10th Date = If(Day([Date]) <11,1,0)
```

[image: 1st to 10th Date]

This can then be used to either filter out the dates past the 10th of each month

Comment: Thx for response, one more question, I have this script to retrieve Sum of MTD for current and previous date, I have hard coded this, but I want something dynamic like Getdate in SQL WITH
 MEMBER [Measures].[LeadsCurrentMTD] AS  SUM(MTD([Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20210216]), [Measures].[Lead Count])
 MEMBER [Measures].[LeadsPreviousMTD] AS SUM(MTD([Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20210216]), [Measures].[Lead Count])
   
SELECT
{ [Measures].[LeadsCurrentMTD]
 ,[Measures].[LeadsPreviousMTD] 
 }
ON 0
FROM [EDW] ;

Comment: This is hard to work through as a comment.  Maybe create a new question, along with a small data example?